# kill jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a carousel in a hidden box. The div gets shown onclick which initializes the plugin which works.

Only problem is when i close the box then open it again it initialiazes the plugin again which gives me two carousels. Is there a way to kill the carousel when i close the div ?

```
    // show hide dropdowns
$("#category").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.style-dropdown, .brand-dropdown').hide();


  $(".category-dropdown").fadeToggle();

  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $('a#style, a#brand').removeClass("active");

  $("#category-slider").flexisel({
        visibleItems: 6,
        animationSpeed: 1000,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoPlaySpeed: 6000,            
        pauseOnHover: true,
        enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
        responsiveBreakpoints: { 
            portrait: { 
                changePoint:480,
                visibleItems: 1
            }, 
            landscape: { 
                changePoint:640,
                visibleItems: 2
            },
            tablet: { 
                changePoint:768,
                visibleItems: 3
            }
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: Can you share more of your code? I don't see why opening the box again would trigger the initialization method. Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Any chance you're calling `$().flexisel()` in a click event?

Comment: do the $("#category-slider").flexisel({ part outside the click() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flexisel plugin doesn't seem to have a destroy() method like for example the jCarousel plugin does. So it is probably not possible to let the carousel kill itself.

But instead of initializing a new carousel on every opening click, why don't you just hide the carousel on closing and showing the same carousel again on opening? Maybe calling the method initializeItems() again (this is called by init() method).

With your updated code I can see that you are calling the flexisel() method on every click event. You should make sure to call it only once. Try something like this:

```
if (!carousel) {
    var carousel = $("#category-slider").flexisel({
    ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Separation of concerns.

Move the initialization method out of the `.click()` function. It should be initialized once on window load (according to the documentation), that's all. Showing and hiding the container that it's in is all that's necessary. If the slider is not in the box, target that element during your click event as well.

```
$("#category").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.style-dropdown, .brand-dropdown').hide();


    $(".category-dropdown").fadeToggle();

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $('a#style, a#brand').removeClass("active");

});

$(window).load(function() {
    $("#category-slider").flexisel({
        visibleItems: 6,
        animationSpeed: 1000,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoPlaySpeed: 6000,            
        pauseOnHover: true,
        enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
        responsiveBreakpoints: { 
            portrait: { 
                changePoint:480,
                visibleItems: 1
            }, 
            landscape: { 
                changePoint:640,
                visibleItems: 2
            },
            tablet: { 
                changePoint:768,
                visibleItems: 3
            }
        }
    }); 
)};
```

EDIT: To clarify, you can call `$("#category-slider").hide();` or toggle some class that will hide show it as well in your click method.